# Null pointer on Viewholder

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save the state of checkboxes in my main activity rather than in my custom adapter. I have checked that the correct data is being stored in the sharedprefs and can retrieve the information successfully but when I try and mark the checkboxes on opening the app the viewholder is null. In theory I understand what the problem is but I have no clue how to fix it.

Here is the part of code from the main activity I am having issues with:

```
for (int i= 0; i<results.size(); i++) {
            result = (Results) customAdapter.getItem(i);
            if (result != null) {
                String RESULT = result.getTitle();
                if (sharedPref.getBoolean(result.getTitle(), false)){
                    Log.i("Saved", result.getTitle());
                    CustomAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = (CustomAdapter.ViewHolder) listView.getTag(i);
                    Log.i("viewHolder", String.valueOf(viewHolder));
                    viewHolder.getCheckBox().setChecked(sharedPref.getBoolean(RESULT, false));
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why can't you make a boolean variable in model class `Results` to hold the state of checkbox and set it from the activity at time you pass data to adapter? So that you can change the check box in `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: I am still very new to this so would not know how to go about it. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You are preparing a `List<Results>` to pass to adapter right? First add a extra boolean variable in `Results` model class to represent the state of checkbox. Now at the time you prepare the list in activity, set the value of this new boolean for each item from the preference. So that your `List<Results>` contain state of the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You are preparing a `List<Results>` to pass to adapter right? First add a extra boolean variable in `Results` model class to represent the state of checkbox. Now at the time you prepare the list in activity, set the value of this new boolean for each item from the preference. So that your `List<Results>` contain state of the checkbox.